# Why do I have to .bind(this) for methods defined in React component class, but not in regular ES6 class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Something that is puzzling me is why when I define a react component class, values contained in the `this` object are undefined in methods defined (`this` is available in lifecycle methods) within the class unless I use `.bind(this)` or define the method using an arrow function for example in the following code `this.state` will be undefined in the `renderElements` function because I did not define it with an arrow function and did not use `.bind(this)`

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { elements: 5 }
    }

    renderElements() {
        const output = [];

        // In the following this.state.elements will be undefined
        // because I have not used  .bind(this) on this method in the constructor
        // example: this.renderElements = this.renderElements.bind(this)
        for(let i = 0; i < this.state.elements; i ++){
            output.push(<div key={i} />);
        }

        return output;
    }

    // .this is defined inside of the lifecycle methods and 
    // therefore do not need call .bind(this) on the render method.
    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.renderElements}></div>
        );
    }
}
```

Then in the following example I do not need to use `.bind(this)` or an arrow function, `this` is available as expected in `speak` function

```
class Animal { 
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    speak() {
        console.log(this.name + ' makes a noise.');
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    speak() {
        console.log(this.name + ' barks.');
    }
}

var d = new Dog('Mitzie');
d.speak();
```

http://jsbin.com/cadoduxuye/edit?js,console

To clarify, my question is two part. One) why in the second code example  do I not need to call `.bind(this)` to the `speak` function, but I do in the React component for the `renderElements` function and Two) why do the lifecycle methods (render, componentDidMount, etc) already have access to the class' `this` object, but `renderElements` does not.

In the React docs it says the following

> [React Component Class] Methods follow the same semantics as regular ES6 classes, meaning that they don't automatically bind this to the instance.

But clearly they do, as the second code example I've posted shows.

**Update**

Both links in the first two comments show a working example of React classes NOT using `.bind(this)` on class methods and it works fine. But still in the docs is explicitly says you need to bind your methods, or use an arrow function. In a project using gulp and babel I can reproduce. Could it mean browsers have updated things?

**Update 2**

My initial code example had `this.renderElements()` called directly in the render function. That would work as expected without binding the function, or defining it with an arrow function. The issue occurs when I put the function as an `onClick` handler.

**Update 3**

> The issue occurs when I put the function as an `onClick` handler.

In fact it is not an issue at all. The context of `this` changes when passed to the onClick handler, so that's just how JS works.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/3ttpydsn/)

Comment: @Oriol I can reproduce on a project using gulp and babel, but you are right I created a js bin and can't reproduce. Why then would the React docs (and example) about using es6 classes explicity state you need to use .bind(this) on your methods defined in your class. Here's my working example as well: http://jsbin.com/warapofila/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Event handlers in the component will not be bound automatically to the component instance like other methods ( life cycle methods...).

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   render(){
      return (
         <div onClick={this.renderElements}>
             {this.renderElements()} <-- `this` is still in side the MyComponent context
         </div>
      )
   }
}
//under the hood

var instance = new MyComponent();
var element = instance.render();
//click on div
element.onClick() <-- `this` inside renderElements refers to the window object now
```

Check this example to understand `this` more :

```
class Animal { 
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    speak() {
        console.log(this.name + ' makes a noise.');
    }  
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    run(){
       console.log(this.name + ' runs');
    }
    speak() {
        console.log(this.name + ' barks.');
        this.run(); <-- `this` is still in the Dog context
        return {onRun : this.run};
    }
}

var d = new Dog('Mitzie');
var myDog = d.speak();
myDog.onRun() <-- `this` is now in the global context which is the `window` object
```

You can check this [article](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/) for more information.

Comment: *"render method is called outside the component context so all this.functionName inside render method will refer to the window object."* That is incorrect.

Comment: @FelixKling fix it. I hope it's correct now. Thanks ! ;)

Comment: `render` in not called in the global context. React will call `component.render()`, so `this` will refer to `component`. Or am I misunderstanding what you mean by that sentence?

Comment: I think you're right. I confused myself as well. Sorry for false information.

Comment: Wow everyone should read the given article. It explains this well. And this is definitely the correct answer.

Answer (score 19):

The value of `this` primarily depends on how the function is *called*. Given `d.speak();`, `this` will refer to `d` because the function is called as an "object method".

But in `<div>{this.renderElements}</div>` you are *not* calling the function. You are passing the function to React which will call it somehow. When it is called, React doesn't know which object the function "belonged" to so it cannot set the right value for `this`. Binding solves that

I actually think what you really want is

```
<div>{this.renderElements()}</div>
//         call function ^^
```

i.e *call* the function as an object method. Then you don't have to bind it.

---

Have a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to learn more about `this`.

Answer (score 9):

**Functions in ES6 Classes** - the case is explained very well by @Felix Kling. Every time you call a function on an object, `this` points to the object.

**Lifecycle methods in React.Component** - whenever React instantiates your component like `myComponent = new MyComponent()` it knows which object to call the lifecycle methods on, namely *myComponent*. So a simple call `myComponent.componentDidUpdate()` makes `this` available in the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. Same for the other lifecycle methods.

**Handlers & Bound in React.Component** - `this.state` is `undefined`, because `this` is actually `window` - log it and see. The reason is that *React invokes handlers on the global context, unless you have the handler bound to another context which overrides* `window` (see @Phi Nguyen's answer also). 
I think they have done that to allow you more flexibility, because in complex applications your handler may come from another component passed through props and then you would like to have the possibility to say: *"Hey, React - `this` is not my component, but it's parent."*

---

React's documentation is a bid misleading when it says

> Methods follow the same semantics as regular ES6 classes, meaning that
>   they don't automatically bind this to the instance.

What they mean is that

```
var dog = new Dog('Mitzie');
speak = d.speak;

dog.speak() // this will be dog, because the function is called on dog
speak() // this will be window, and not dog, because the function is not bound
```

Answer (score 2):

1.
[Arrow Functions:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An **arrow function expression** has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and **lexically binds the this value** (`does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target`). Arrow functions are always `anonymous`. These function expressions are best suited for **non-method functions and they can not be used as constructors**.

[Function.prototype.bind():](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

> The **bind()** method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

2.[Component Specs and Lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)

> To be absolutely clear: Most lifecycle methods are not bound, but called on an instance using the dot notation (true for `componentWillMount`, `componentWillUnmount`, `componentWillReceiveProps` and so on...), except `componentDidMount` which is bound to the instance since it gets enqueued into the transaction.

Answer (score -1):

Just always put the `autoBind(this);` code in your constructor and never worry about method pointers.

`npm install --save auto-bind-inheritance`

```
const autoBind = require('auto-bind-inheritance');

class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    autoBind(this);
    this.name = name;
  }

  printName() { console.log(this.name); }
  ...
}

let m = new Animal('dog');
let mpntr = m.printName;
m.printName() //> 'dog'
mpntr()       //> 'dog', because auto-bind, binds 'this' to the method.
```