# how to read this.props in a function

Tags: reactjs, null, ecmascript-6

I'm new to reactjs with ES6, the problem is that I can not read the 'this.props.productId' property inside the onDelete () function, this is the error: `DeleteProductComponent.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null` can anyone give me an optimum solution or tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class DeleteProductComponent extends Component {

     componentDidMount() {

        $('.page-header h1').text('Delete Product');

        }

onDelete(){

var id = this.props.productId;

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/my-app/public/delete.php",
            type : "POST",
            contentType : 'application/json',
            data : JSON.stringify({'id' : id}),
            success : function(response) {
                this.props.changeAppMode('read');
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, resp, text){
                // show error in console
                console.log(xhr, resp, text);
            }
        });
    }

    // handle save changes button here
    // handle save changes button clicked

      render () {

        return (
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-md-3'></div>
                <div className='col-md-6'>
                    <div className='panel panel-default'>
                        <div className='panel-body text-align-center'>Are you sure?</div>
                        <div className='panel-footer clearfix'>
                            <div className='text-align-center'>
                                <button onClick={this.onDelete}
                                    className='btn btn-danger m-r-1em'>Yes</button>
                                <button onClick={() => this.props.changeAppMode('read')}
                                    className='btn btn-primary'>No</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='col-md-3'></div>
            </div>
        );
      }

    } 
    export default DeleteProductComponent;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I have to .bind(this) for methods defined in React component class, but not in regular ES6 class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552536/why-do-i-have-to-bindthis-for-methods-defined-in-react-component-class-but-n)

Comment: you forgot to `bind` the **onDelete function**, use this: `<button onClick={this.onDelete.bind(this)}....` or use arrow function like this: `<button onClick={()=>this.onDelete()}....`

Comment: @MayankShukla this will work but it's a bad practice to bind it inside the render method as it will create a new instance on each render, bad for performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind `onDelete()` function to the component by 2 ways:

**In the `constructor`**:

```
class DeleteProductComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onDelete = this.onDelete.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {}

  onDelete() {}

  render() {}

}
```

**Or use ES6's syntax** for `onDelete()` (then it will be bound to the component by itself):

```
 onDelete = () => {

    var id = this.props.productId;

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/my-app/public/delete.php",
        type : "POST",
        contentType : 'application/json',
        data : JSON.stringify({'id' : id}),
        success : function(response) {
            this.props.changeAppMode('read');
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, resp, text){
            // show error in console
            console.log(xhr, resp, text);
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and for the suggestion of two ways, it works perfect!

Comment: Glad you had it working ^^ ! You can ping me for further issues with reactjs, If I can I will try to help!

Comment: what is this.props.changeAppMode?

Answer (score 1):

You in `class`s you need to bind `this` to the `class`.
The best place to do it is in the constructor of the `class` as it will run only the first time the class instantiate rather then doing it inside the render method witch will create a new instance of the handler on each render.
So you should do this in the `constructor`:

```
    class DeleteProductComponent extends Component {
        constructor(props, context) {
            super(props, context);

            this.onDelete = this.onDelete.bind(this);
        }
    //.... rest of the class
```

Comment: You have been very right, I forgot this part completely thank you very much !.