# How to properly bind a function in a onChange event?

Tags: reactjs, closures

I have an `onChange` prop like so:

```
onChange={ (value) => this._onChange(value) }
```

and this works perfectly fine. However, if I try to abstract that so that I'm not using an inline function, I get an error.

```
_onChangeHandler = () => (value) => this._onChange(value)
```

Then in the component,

```
onChange={ this._onChangeHandler() }
```

This completely breaks the component. Why does this not work?

**Update:**

The onChange is for a form field, and in the input element, when I type in it, I see `[object Object]`

Comment: In what way does it not work? Are you getting error messages?

Comment: Could you post a more complete code snippet? Also, can you determine what is being called? (Maybe putting console.log messages in your various handlers?)

Answer (score 0):

I normally do

```
onChange={ this.onChange.bind(this) }
```

So you can use `this` reference.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to execute your factory method?

```
onChange={ this._onChangeHandler() } // <--notice the parens
```

Comment: I assumed that you had a reason for using a factory method. Otherwise, @Michael's solution is probably better. (Although I think you might want to move the bind to the constructor so it's not re-run on every render)

Comment: @specklecarp Even with the invocation, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
_onChangeHandler = (value) => this._onChange(value)
```

instead of

```
_onChangeHandler = () => (value) => this._onChange(value)
```

Because this returns a function which returns a function which calls `this._onChange` with given value.

But what you really want is a function which calls `this._onChange` with given value.

Also, don't call the function in your JSX, instead just assign it. Otherwise what you assign for `onChange` is what returned by the function.

```
onChange={ this._onChangeHandler }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following case, you are violating the syntax for arrow function in

```
_onChangeHandler = () => (value) => this._onChange(value)
```

An arrow function takes the function params afte the `=` sign an the function body after the `=>` sign, so it should be

```
_onChangeHandler = (value) => this._onChange(value)
```

Also when you call like

```
   onChange={ this._onChangeHandler() }
```

You are not assigning the onChange event a function but a value which is evaluated everytime the component renders, now since your call `this._onChange(value)` in this function, and it may perform an action that will lead to the DOM being rendered again, so onChange will be evaluated again and hence the function, thus going into an infinite loop and breaking the code. You should vall it like

```
onChange={ this._onChangeHandler.bind(this,value)}
```

or

```
onChange={()=> this._onChangeHandler(value) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `_onChangeHandler` to the component, which has 2 ways:

1/ **Using `.bind()` manually**:

```
_onChangeHandler(value) {
  return this._onChange(value);
}
```

Then in the component: (*bind the method here*)

```
onChange={ this._onChangeHandler.bind(this) }
```

2/ **Using es6's syntax, so the `_onChangeHandler` is bound by itself:**

```
_onChangeHandler = (value) => this._onChange(value);
```

Then in the component: (don't use `this._onChangeHandler()`, remove the brackets)

```
onChange={ this._onChangeHandler }
```

=====

If this doesn't work yet, feel free to post some errors on your console, thanks

For your reference on how to bind methods, please read my answer here:

[how to read this.props in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43956861/how-to-read-this-props-in-a-function/43957669#43957669)