# How does event handlers with arrow functions achieve context binding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I know about the general theory of `this` binding (function call site what matters, implicit, explicit binding, etc...) and the methods to solving the problem of this binding in React so it always points to what I want `this` to be (binding in constructor, arrow functions, etc), but I am struggling to get the inner mechanisms.

Take a look at these two pieces of code:

```
class demo extends React.component {
  goToStore(event) {
    console.log(this)
  }

  render() {
    <button onClick={(e) => this.goToStore(e)}>test</button>
  }
}
```

vs.

```
class demo extends React.component {
  goToStore(event) {
    console.log(this)
  }

  render() {
    <button onClick={this.goToStore}>test</button>
  }
}
```

What I know is that:

- in both versions we end up successfully in the goToStore method, because the `this` inside the `render()` method is automatically bound (by React) to the component instance
- the first one succeeds because of that,
- the second one fails, because class methods in es6 are not bound to the component instance, thus resolving `this` in the method to `undefined`

In theory in the first version as far as I understand, the following occurs:

1. the button click handler is an anonymous **arrow** function, so whenever I reference `this` inside of it, it picks up `this` from the environment (in this case from `render()`)
2. then it calls the `goToStore` method, that is a regular function.
3. because the call seems to fit the rules of implicit binding (`object.function()`) `object` will be the context object and in such function calls it will be used as `this`
4. so, inside the `goToStore` method the lexically picked up this (used as a context object) will resolve to the component instance correctly

I feel 3. and 4. is not the case here, because then it would apply to the 2. case:

```
<button onClick={this.goToStore}>test</button>
```

Also with `this` the context object.

What is happening exactly in this particular case, step-by-step?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the MDN docs states

> An arrow function does not have its own this; the this value of the
>   enclosing execution context is used

So you would think of

```
onClick={(e) => this.goToStore(e)}
```

as being an anonymous function which can be written as

```
    (e) => { 
         return this.goToStore(e) 
    }
```

Now here in this anonymous function `this` refers to the lexical context of the render function which in turn refers to the React Class instance.

Now

**Context** is most often determined by how a function is invoked. When a function is called as a method of an object, this is set to the object the method is called on:

```
var obj = {
    foo: function() {
        return this;   
    }
};

obj.foo() === obj; // true
```

The same principle applies when invoking a function with the new operator to create an instance of an object. When invoked in this manner, the value of this within the scope of the function will be set to the newly created instance:

```
function foo() {
    alert(this);
}

foo() // window
new foo() // foo
```

When called as an unbound function, this will default to the global context or window object in the browser.

So here since the function is called like `this.goToStore()`  this inside it will refer to the context of React component.

However when you write `onClick={this.goToStore}`, the function is not executed but a reference of it is assigned to the onClick function, which then later invokes it, causing `this` to be undefined inside the function as the function runs on the context of the  `window` object.

Now even though `onClick={(e) => this.goToStore(e)}` works, whenever render is called a new function instance is created. In your case its easy to avoid, just by created the function goToStore using arrow function syntax.

```
goToStore = (e) => {

}
```

Check the docs for more details on [**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Now I get it, so later when the click happens, the function reference is invoked with a simple function call, like `onClick()`, resulting in the default binding rule, that is window.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In case 1, as you said, the context is picked up from the environment.
For case 2, you have to remember that the class syntax in ES6 is just syntactic sugar over the more cumbersome prototype syntax on which JavaScript relies upon to implement OOP.

Basically, in the second example, all you are doing is something like this:

```
function demo() {
   // this is the constructor
}
demo.prototype.goToStore = function() {
  // handler
};
demo.prototype.render = function() {
  return React.createElement('button', onClick: this.goToStore);
}
```

As you can see, the `onClick` property is just receiving a reference to the function. Whenever that function is called, no `this` will be binded, and it will be run in the context of the `window` object.

In older libraries, prior to the existence of modern transpilers, we used to do something like this ALL OVER THE PLACE:

```
function demo() {
   // this is the constructor     
   this.goToStore = this.goToStore.bind(this);
   // same for every other handler
}
demo.prototype.goToStore = function() {
   // handling code.
};
demo.prototype.render = function() {
  // this goToStore reference has the proper this binded.
  return React.createElement('button', onClick: this.goToStore);
}
```

Nowadays, this last example I put is automatically handled by all modern transpilers. Babel basically does the autobinding in the constructor when you use the fat arrow method syntax in any class:

```
class demo extends Anything {
  constructor() {
  }
  bindedMethod = () => {
    // my context will always be the instance!
  }
}
```

With subtle differences, all transpilers will move the definition of the `bindedMethod` to the constructor, where the `this` will be bound to the current instance running the constructor.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. Your answer was just as good as the one from Shubham, I would've accepted it as well, if it was allowed to accept two answers.

Answer (score 0):

When the render code is executed, `this` refers to the component class, so it is able to reference the correct function. This means that `element.onClick` points to the `goToStore` method.

When that function is called in the browser, it's called from the context of the html element (i.e. `element.onClick()`). So unless the `goToStore` method is bound to the context of the component class, it will inherit `this` from the context of the element.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39552949/4175836) provides some more relevant information and further reading.