# How to only update one element within a component without rerendering the whole component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to optimize the performance of app. I've found that the issue is that one of my components re-renders on a condition that I set and it contains a significant amount of data. I wanted to know if it were possible to not re-render the whole component, but to only re-render the element that has changed?

I've already tried using PureComponent, but that did not have enough control for me. I'm currently using shouldComponentUpdate.

Answer (score 1):

By default every time a parent component is re rendered all the children nodes will be rendered as well, if you know for sure that a given component will always render the same content given the same props then you could turn it into a `PureComponent`, a pure component performs a shallow comparison `obj1 === obj2` in props and only re-render when a change occurs. If you need a more complex comparison logic then `shouldComponentUpdate` is the way to go:

```
shoudComponentUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(prevProps.items.length !== this.props.items.length) return true

    return false
}
```

By default this method always returns true, unless you explicitly tells it not to. The functional version of `shouldComponentUpdate` is `React.memo`. But keep in mind that comparisons take time, and the amount of processing required to perform a comparison grows with the complexity. Use it carefully.

Comment: So, I've thought about your answer. I have an additional question. I'm thinking of extracting the portions of the component I do not want to update, into a Fragment (Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.). Since it does not add extra nodes, would this prevent re-rendering?

Comment: No. Just wrap your components in a Fragment will not prevent then from render. Fragment is only used when you need to return adjacent JSX elements. Different things...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest breaking out the piece that needs to be updated into it's own component and use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) or PureComponent like you were saying. This might also help.

[React partial render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589002/react-partial-render)