# Why do I need 'bind(this)' in the example above

Tags: reactjs

I begin read the Reactjs and faced with a question in example. In constructor will add

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
```

But I can't understand, what role do they play out and why are they needed? Code will work, if a method is change to the arrow func. Thanks.

Full example:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {value: ''};

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
           <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <label>
                Name:
                   <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
               </label>
               <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
           </form>
        );
    }
   }
```

Comment: Because of `this`. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: It's detaily described in [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)

Comment: Otherwise NameForm's this (including React.Component) is not passed to onChange event handler and this.setState cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 2):

Because the function will be called from the global context, so `this` will not refer to your class instance, it will be `undefined` Why ? Because when a `change` event occurs, React will simply call your method like this `youHandler(event)`, you can see that the function will not have `this` value as it's called from the global context. I give you an example in pure javascript (outside of react scope) :

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" onChange="myFunction()">

<script>
 "use strict";

 function myFunction() {
   console.log(this); // this is undefined here
 }
</script>
```

So you need to use `bind` method to set the value of `this`, which will be equal to the current class instance

Moreover an arrow function does not have its own `this`; the this value of the enclosing lexical context is used when you create an arrow function. You can read the doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this) So if you write :

```
handleChange = event => {
   this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}
```

you have to ask yourself the following question : What is the value of `this` when the `handleChange` function is created ? Here it will be equal to the current instance of `NameForm` class, and this is actually what you want.

Comment: Not true, `handleChange`'s `this` inside of the component will refer to the component context.

Comment: yes, but when you pass the function to the `onChange` props it will be called from the global context

Comment: We talk about calling it as `onChange={this.handleChange}`

Comment: yes and the problem is : `this` will be undefined. Why ? because it's not called from the component context

Comment: Is not going to be undefined. Try it.

Comment: If you remove `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);` it will be undefined, Look at this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-chdk96

Comment: Simple example, have a look: https://codepen.io/nataliyajurbenko/pen/JpJgmE

Comment: Sorry, but  `handleChange` from your link (example) is not an arrow function.

Comment: But I mean creating the function without using arrow function, the author ask about why should he use `bind` or `arrow function`. I tried to explained why it's not working when using es5 function. At the end of my post, I explain why it's working using `arrow function`

Comment: @loan The point of the question is to explain why `bind` is necessary, or why an arrow function works. Without `bind` or the arrow function `this` will not refer to the component instance; with either, it will. OP is asking why use `bind` (if not using an arrow function) etc. Olivier is explaining why `bind` is necessary if it's not an arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between them.

However, this is a part of proposed class fields for arrow functions and it isn't a ES6 feature.

Have a look at other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48740930/1392463).

Comment: Using the arrow function form does not require re-binding it; that's the whole point of using an arrow function. The other difference is that using `bind` creates a new instance value based off the prototype's method while the arrow function version is always off the current instance. The `bind` here would still create a new function.