# this in React Native class method

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx, es6-class, arrow-functions

I have this React Native component:

```
type Props = { image: string, onPress: Function, text: string, title: String };
type States = { loadError: boolean };

export default class ProductRow extends Component<Props, States> {
  state = {
    loadError: false
  };

  changeToDefaultImg() {
    this.setState({ loadError: true });
  }

  render() {
    let img = this.state.loadError ? (
      <SImage source={PLACEHOLDER} style={styles.placeholderImg} />
    ) : (
      <Image
        source={{ uri: this.props.image }}
        indicator={ProgressCircleSnail}
        indicatorProps={{ color: mainDark }}
        onError={() => this.changeToDefaultImg()}
        resizeMode="contain"
        style={styles.image}
        threshold={0}
      />
    );

    return (
      // JSX
    );
  }
}
```

You can see that I haven't written:

```
constructor(props) { 
  super(props)
  this.changeToDefaultImg = this.changeToDefaultImg.bind(this); 
}
```

But I can use this function without any errors.

Please, explain to me, why it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two ways to make a class function work.

**1. Declare it as an arrow function**

If you declare `changeToDefaultImg` as `changeToDefaultImg = () = {...}` and pass it as `onError={this.changeToDefaultImg}`, it will work normally.

**2. Calling the function inside an arrow function**

If you call it inside a arrow function like `onError={() => this.changeToDefaultImg()}`, it will also work normally.

As you can see, you are doing the second case. If you don't use arrow functions, you will be getting the wrong `this`.

You should notice that using the first way is better because you don't create a instance of an arrow function on every render like in the second way.

You should take a look at some [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699573/correct-use-of-arrow-functions-in-react).

Answer (score 2):

It works because:

1. You [initialized `state`](https://codeburst.io/use-class-properties-to-clean-up-your-classes-and-react-components-93185879f688#199e) as a [class property](https://codeburst.io/use-class-properties-to-clean-up-your-classes-and-react-components-93185879f688#48e4), so you don't need a [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor).
2. You call `changeToDefaultImg()` inside an anonymous [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), so you don't need to use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to save a [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Read [this article](https://codeburst.io/use-class-properties-to-clean-up-your-classes-and-react-components-93185879f688) for more explanations.