# Issue in passing a parameterized component to FlatList

Tags: react-native, properties, react-native-flatlist, parameterized, prop

I am trying to create a custom seperator component for FlatList such that it changes color based on a prop. that's passed to it.

Here's my Seperator component :

```
ItemSeparator = (seperatorColor) => (
    <View style={{height: 0.5, width: '100%', backgroundColor: seperatorColor?seperatorColor:'black'}}/>
);
```

Here's the usage :

```
        <FlatList
          data = {array}
          keyExtractor = { (item) => { return item}}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparator('black')}
          ListHeaderComponent={ItemSeparator}
          ListFooterComponent={ItemSeparator} />
```

This gives this error : 
[image]

However, if i don't pass the argument it works fine:

```
        <FlatList
          data = {array}
          keyExtractor = { (item) => { return item}}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={ItemSeparator}
          ListFooterComponent={ItemSeparator} />
```

Whats the right way to pass this property? And why is above not working?

Comment: in keyextractor just return id except whole item

Comment: `ItemSeparatorComponent={() => ItemSeparator('black')}`

Comment: @Milore : Thanks, that works. Do you know why ItemSeperator('black') does not work?

I believe when we say  ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparator} , the curly braces indicate that we are trying to point to a JS function named ItemSeperator. Then {ItemSeperator('black')} should call that function with an argument. Why does that not work?

Comment: Please, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48700540/7581249)