# Is it true that in React, using an arrow function onClick={() => this.doSomething()} can significantly impact the React app's performance?

Tags: reactjs

I heard in an [Udemy ReactJS class](https://www.udemy.com/course/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/), using an arrow function for an onClick handler will cause performance issue and unnecessary render for the component:

```
return (
  <button onClick={() => this.doSomething()}>
```

or what about

```
return (
  <Foo onClick={() => this.doSomething()}>
```

Is it true?  I don't quite see how it can cause unnecessary re-render, as the whole subtree from this component and down should need to be re-rendered anyway.

---

The recommendation is to use one of the following:

1) use

```
return (
  <button onClick={this.doSomething.bind(this)}>
```

2) in the constructor

```
this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
```

3) in the class definition, use arrow function instead:

```
const doSomething = () => {   };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct use of arrow functions in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699573/correct-use-of-arrow-functions-in-react)

Comment: I also made the question: `<button>` vs `<Foo>`... if it is a button, it might be true React will need to update the actual DOM... what about `Foo`... it is best to keep the props as static as possible so that the actual DOM is touched as little as possible? (the arrow function is re-instantiated every time as something new)

Comment: so I think the issue is not about re-rendering. It is about updating the actual DOM...

Comment: so even `onClick={this.doSomething.bind(this)}` is not good, because it is creating a new function every time

Answer (score 0):

becuase in javascript Functions are First class objects, so this function

```
<button onClick={() => this.doSomething()}>
```

when a re-render occures due to a state change, the **render** method will be called again.
so `{() => this.doSomething()}` will be created again, and react comprase the object references. although it seems the same to you, its not for javascript and react, becuase `{() => this.doSomething()}` will be created again, since its an object, and its reference is a different one from the one in the previous render.

Comment: so it is a new function... so I think the issue is that the button is the actual DOM needs some maintenance because now the listener is a different function... React needs to update the actual DOM, that's the issue

Comment: yes, its a completely new object created in memory