# ReactJS: Too many re-renders in function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a small function, which makes a likable Button. My function should work, but the error I get is too many re-renders (even tough the setState only gets called onClick)
Code below:

```
    function ClickMeToLike(){
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Col><p>
    {
    isLiked ?
    <Icon.Heart onClick={setIsLiked(true)}/> :
    <Icon.HeartFill onClick={setIsLiked(false)}/>
    }
    </p></Col>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use an arrow function in your onClick

try this

```
onClick = {() => setIsLiked(true)}
```

best practice is to use what the answer above me is though and define a separate function to handle your clicks

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What's the difference though?

Comment: If Arrow functions are used in render method, then they create a new instance everytime render is called just like how bind would work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699573/correct-use-of-arrow-functions-in-react this is a great read to understand what I am talking about

Comment: Oh! Thanks! Very nice of you to help me :)

Comment: no worries! I am in the process of learning react as well..... so this fixed your issue??

Comment: Yes it luckily did

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you shouldn't handle clicking inside a return. You need to define a separate function for handling the click.

```
function ClickMeToLike(){
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = React.useState(false);

  onClick = () => setIsLiked(!isLiked);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Button</button>
      {isLiked?"clicked":"not clicked"}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: So the problem is the inline-if?