# Confusion with arrow functions react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, arrow-functions

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

function Todo({todo,index,removeTodo}){
    return(
    <div className="todo"> 
        {todo.text}


        <div>
            <button onClick={() => removeTodo(index)} > Remove </button>

        </div>
    </div>
    );
}

export default Todo;
```

Can someone explain why I need to put the () => before calling the function?

Comment: `() => { /* function code */ }` is an anonymous function, it is similar to writing `function() { /* function code */}` except the anonymous function is automatically bound to the scope it is created in. Why the anonymous function is needed here is because `onClick` provides a React.MouseEvent parameter and not the index that `removeTodo` is expecting, therefore `removeTodo` needed to be wrapped to provide the expected parameter.

Comment: what is a react MouseEvent and why would it affect what I pass into removeTodo, would index not always just be a number?

Comment: `React.MouseEvent` is the Typescript type for a mouse related event in React. button's `onClick` has a type of `(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void;`. It impacts how `removeTodo` is called as if you were to have `<button onClick={removeTodo} />` then `removeTodo` would receive a React.MouseEvent and not an index. If you had `<button onClick={removeTodo(index)} />` the `removeTodo` would be executed during render and the return of the function assigned to `onClick` (which I assume is undefined). This leaves you with wrapping `removeTodo` in an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this post: [Correct use of arrow functions in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699573/correct-use-of-arrow-functions-in-react)

Should be helpful. Be sure to reference the answer, not the question in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` is a native js event listener that **requires** a function and it passes an event object in it,
if your `removeTodo` function is returning a function then it should work, but then your function should look like this:

```
function removeTodo(index) {

 return () => {}
}
```

which I don't think is a case.

Comment: so what your saying is that if I pass it in as just removeTodo it is an object, not a function?

Comment: Like this `onClick={removeTodo}` it's fine but then your `index` argument is an event object from click event, and like this `onClick={removeTodo(index)}` it is going to throw an error because you are assigning undefined to a function.

Comment: what do you mean by an event object, is it not just a number?