# Difference between function invocation and function reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In JSX, what is the difference between this

```
<div onClick={this.someFunction} />
```

and

```
<div onClick={() => this.someFunction()} />
```

and also, when is one recommended over the other in an `onClick` event?

I have had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886272/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-call-and-function-reference) but it is not answering my question really.

Comment: Both examples use a function reference.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So are you saying those are both the same just different syntax?

Comment: Exactly. Your second code example just is more bloated and less readable.

Comment: If it's about react, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47679673/how-does-event-handlers-with-arrow-functions-achieve-context-binding)

Comment: @KirillSimonov, thanks, that actually helped a lot in clearing the confusion. So it seems to me that the two ways mentioned above are actually different  and not the same as connexo said.

Answer (score 0):

No there is a difference, first one won't work with onchange but second one work fine, because second one bind this with class automatically, first one don't .

Comment: Oh well, first this is about `onClick` not `onChange` and binding is not the issue here. For instance the binding could have been done at constructor level

Comment: They actually don't. It seems that the first example will pass a reference to the function and the second one will pass the return value of that function.