# Javascript "This" differences in arrow functions

Tags: javascript, this, arrow-functions

here are two simple codes:

```
let myObject = {
objectName: () => {
    console.log(this);
}
};

myObject.objectName();
```

First code print "this" value as: { }

```
let myObject = {
objectName: function() {
    console.log(this);
}
};

myObject.objectName();
```

Second code print "this" value as: { objectName: [Function: objectName] }

Can somebody explain in plain English why "this" in arrow function has different value ? 
Thank you!

Comment: because, well ... [here's some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Arrow functions adopt the *this* of their enclosing scope.

Answer (score 0):

An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own `this` , `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`. The `this` value of the enclosing execution `context` is used.

If you don't use an arrow function, a function gets its `this` value from where it is called.

Check this for more details

[How does event handlers with arrow functions achieve context binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47679673/how-does-event-handlers-with-arrow-functions-achieve-context-binding/47680408#47680408)