# I don't know the difference between the two in the event handling process in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

`onRemove(id)` is a function which filtering id that gets from parameter.

case 1)

```
const namesList = names.map(name => (<li key={name.id} onDoubleClick={onRemove(name.id)}>
{name.text}</li>));
```

case 2)

```
const namesList = names.map(name => (<li key={name.id} onDoubleClick={()=> onRemove(name.id)}>
{name.text}</li>));
```

I don't know the difference between case 1 and case 2.

Comment: Then use a better code editor and format the code: the function inside the `map` in the first case returns something _completely different_ from the second case.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you are passing parameter `id` without using binding and in the second case you are using arrow function to pass the parameter which is equvalent to binding.

### Expected behaviour

**case 1** `onRemove(id)` function will be call immediately after component render (in example you will see console log on each refresh)

**case 2** `onRemove(id)` function will be call when you make double click(in example you will see console log on double click)

To know more about passing parameter and how to bind a function follow [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47679673/how-does-event-handlers-with-arrow-functions-achieve-context-binding)

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-kirch-gmus0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)